# Can't connect client to server using socket

Tags: linux, sockets, client

I am having a problem when I try to connect a client to a server.The method of running is : server 51717 and client localhost 51717.
My problem is , when I run the client I'm getting this error on the command line : `No command 'client found, did you mean : Command 'jclient' from package 'julius' (multiverse). client :command not found`.I must specify that the server is running when I run the client. Please let me know if somebody knows how can solve this.Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What kind of server are you talking about? Is there any programming language involved?

Comment: The language is c, and i am just trying to run an exemple i found with a comunication server-client using sockets. The problem i get when i try to run client is not only for that particular exemple, it shows up when i use a socket communication.

Comment: I hope you are having compiled version of the code, that you are executing from the command line.

Comment: Yes, and the compilation worked without errors or warnings.

Comment: please show us that example and what you did to run it. It looks like you are trying to run the source code as a shell script or something like that...

Comment: http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html .This is the link.To compile i used gcc -o server server.c  and gcc -o client client.c  .To run i used exactly the instructions from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want to run programs in current directory.The command you may use as:

`./server 51717`

`./client localhost 51717`

Answer (score 1):

`gcc -o client client.c` compiles the source file `client.c` and creates from it a binary `client` in the current directory.

As the current directory is not in your $PATH you have to explicitly tell you shell to take the binary from the current directory using `./client`.

If you simply type `client` your shell searches $PATH does not find any tool called client and tries to be "helpful" telling you that the ubuntu package "julius" contains a command "jclient" - but that is not what you want. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think your application uses [Julius](http://julius.sourceforge.jp). Check if installed correctly and you can solve the problem using [form discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-os-discuss/HJUtE4TzLhw).